# Pairing multiple iOS devices with one bluetooth keyboard

Tags: iphone, ipad, keyboard, bluetooth

I have a [Keys to go](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/keys-to-go-ipad) Bluetooth keyboard that I use with my iPad. When I turned off the Bluetooth of my iPad, and paired the keyboard with my iPhone, it worked fine with the iPhone. The issue is that when I turn off the iPhone Bluetooth trying pair back to iPad, the iPad doesn't recognize the keyboard. I could make the re-paring to my iPad only after my forcefully un-paring the device manually with my iPhone.

I just expected that the Bluetooth keyboard can connect any devices nearby, but this may not be the case.
Is this expected behavior or Bluetooth keyboards? Is this specific to iOS devices?

Comment: It's probably a problem on the side of the keyboard which can only keep so many devices paired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst you can pair one master with many slaves, as far as I'm aware, you cannot connect one slave to many masters simultaneously.
You need to un-pair & re-pair each time.

There is a rather complex guide to piconet & scatternet technology at the [Bluetooth Developer Portal](https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/Topology.aspx)

Bluetooth v4.0 spec distinctly says it cannot be done, however v4.1 says it can - so it may depend on which version is used in the device.
http://9to5mac.com/2013/12/05/bluetooth-4-1-will-bring-more-reliable-automatic-connections-multiple-roles-more-via-software-update/